# How to reference creator object in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-2.7

I have a question.

There are two classes: A and B. A creates object of type B. So from A, it is easy to access methods of B, but how can I access methods of object A from object B? I am trying to use bidirectional signal-slot mechanism in Qt. A can easily have a slot for a signal in B, but B cannot see signals in A.

I have a vague idea that somehow the creator class can be referenced as a 'member' while an object is being created, but I am not sure how to do code this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the creator as an argument to the constructor:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, creator):
        self._creator = creator   # or do something else with it
```

Use as:

```
class A(object):
    def somemethod(self):
        b = B(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works when I send strings and print them, but when I try to send images with signal like this:

self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('speak'),tempimage)

And connect it from inside B like this:

self.connect(self._creator, QtCore.SIGNAL('speak'),self.printSuccess)

Where printSuccess prints the size of the image, then I get an error:

"RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted"

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta: I don't actually know a thing about PyQt, so I can't help you with that. Sorry.

Comment: which argument is telling you it has been deleted?

Comment: I needed to have the parent class available in one of my applications and I ended up using this method. It worked for me. Also, to clarify, you can't or shouldn't really try to "identify" the creator object based on the object itself due to the duck typing nature of Python.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this automatically. You'll just have to give each B a reference to A when you create it, something like `b_instance.parent = a_instance`.

Comment: Yes, I did not mean automatically :)
But where shall I write this? Inside class A immediately after the object creation?