# Signal-Slot Connection between Creator and Created Class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-2.7, signals-slots

I have a question.

I have two classes, A and B. A creates object of type B, and also emits signals like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), "Hello World")
```

B can see methods in A as A passed 'self' as an argument to the constructor while creating B, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148804/1062484).

Now, I want to write a slot in B for that signal emitted in A like this:

```
self.connect(self._creator, QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), mySlot)
```

Here I would like to mention that both A and B inherit from QtCore.QObject. The method mySlot is just supposed to print the value it receives as the argument from the signal.

When I run it, I get this error:

> QObject.emit(SIGNAL(), ...): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QObject'

In the **init**() of both the classes, I have added this:

```
QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
```

Without adding this, I get the error:

> RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted

I am not experienced in Qt. I do not understand what is going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first argument of unbound method must have type 'QObject'

As error says, you need to pass reference to `A` for `QtCore.QObject.emit` or call it with instance method:

```
QtCore.QObject.emit(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), "Hello World")
```

Or

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), "Hello World")
```

Fully working example (if I understood you right):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class A(QtCore.QObject):
    mySignal = QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal(QString)')
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    def create_b(self):
        return B(self)

    def some_action(self):
        QtCore.QObject.emit(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), "Hello World")
        # this will work too
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), "Hello World")

class B(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, creator):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self._creator = creator
        self.connect(self._creator, QtCore.SIGNAL('mySignal'), self.mySlot)

    def mySlot(self, str):
        print str

a = A()
b = a.create_b()
a.some_action()
```

Even better solution, is to use [New-style Signals and Slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html)

Here is example for you case:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class A(QtCore.QObject):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    def create_b(self):
        return B(self)

    def some_action(self):
        self.mySignal.emit("Hello World")

class B(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, creator):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self._creator = creator
        self._creator.mySignal.connect(self.mySlot)

    def mySlot(self, str):
        print str

a = A()
b = a.create_b()
a.some_action()
```

Comment: Actually, it is slightly different from this. B in my case is a thread, so inside A, I have:

`self.b = B(self)`
`self.b.start()`

When I run your example, it runs fine, but when I use it in my case, it says: _underlying C/C++ object has been deleted_

Comment: I understand that this is a problem with ownership semantics, but do not know how to solve this. Someone else created object from A, A created object from B, now A must send signal, and B must have a slot for it. Somehow Python is not understanding the ownership semantics of my coding. But since I have no control over the creation of object from A, and only that can trigger the creation of object from B, I cannot write the object creation statement outside like I could in a small standalone Python script.

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta, Add code that reproduces your problem to the question. It isn't clear. Here's working example with threads http://pastebin.com/RMJtJskV (It's edited code, `QThread.__init__` instead `QObject.__init__`)

Comment: Here it is [link](http://pastebin.com/N87sJ9qe)
This will not execute, because it is a small part of a large amount of code. I have tried to delete most of the noise so that you understand.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the classes cannot inherit from QThread. If they do, other things will stop working :( They are regular threads.

Comment: It's hard to tell why `printSuccess` isn't called. Here's code very close to yours: http://pastebin.com/cUrkQ7fu

Comment: I found out what the problem was. Unlike your code, I inherited from my GUI class in another file, and imported that as package, and created object from it to get the actual GUI to show up. Apparently, Qt has this restriction that the class that directly inherits from the GUI can only catch a signal. So I had to do two depths of backtracing like `self._creator._creator.mySignal.connect(mySlot)` and had to put it in MainWindow.py that inherits from Uic (which I created in QtDesigner). Now things are running fine! :)